# react native vector icons won't show in android device

Tags: android, react-native

I used react-native-vector-icons in my react native project and start app with `npm start`.

Icons are displaying normally in iOS, but won't show in android.

Things I tried:

- three method in the doc of react-native-vector-icons (finally I can see *.tff files in the fonts folder)
- use `react-native run-android` to start app. Icon shows normal but what I want is integrating react native with my existing android app, not a totally RN app.
- use jsbundle file instead of debug server in my app

None of above works

So, should I add something to my existing android app?

I don't know how to solve this problem

---

```
react@15.2.0

react-native@0.30.0

react-native-vector-icons@2.0.3

node v5.10.1

npm v3.8.3
```

Comment: I gave up and ended up manually copying the fonts over to the `myapp/android/app/src/main/assets/` folder from the `myapp/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts` folder..

Answer (score 149):

Open `android/app/build.gradle` and add the following:

```
apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")
```

You can follow the instructions to properly install the module on Android: [react-native-vector-icons#install-android](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons?tab=readme-ov-file#android-setup)

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to rebuild (npx react-native run-android).

Answer (score 44):

I fixed it this by executing:

```
react-native link
react-native run-android
```

Comment: Note that if you run this, you should only run it with the package you want (e.g. `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`), because otherwise you might re-link packages which you configured in a different way. Learned that the hard way

Answer (score 27):

Open terminal on same project path :

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons 
react-native run-android
```

Comment: i have tried this "react-native link react-native-vector-icons" it say unknow comand reac-native. than i tried with npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons it say "error:unknown comand link"

Answer (score 25):

Edit android/app/build.gradle

Just add in dependencies

implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')

Below lines of code are optional if you are using RN >0.60

Edit `android/app/build.gradle` ( NOT `android/build.gradle` ) and add the following:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Edit `android/settings.gradle` to look like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'MyApp'

include ':app'

// Add these two lines
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

references:
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Although, I'd recommend you take off the + signs.

Answer (score 22):

```
In :-   android/app/build.gradle

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

[image]

```
and setting.gradle file add this 

include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect Solution. 100% working. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ali Raza

Comment: Thanks, this solution is worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

After doing the below-Mentioned steps, working Fine.

Before, make sure these steps.

Install package:

```
 yarn add react-native-vector-icons
```

Import: `import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';`

Example code:

```
return (
      <View style={styles.buttonCircle}>
        <Ionicons
          testID="nextButton"
          name="arrow-forward"
          color="rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)"
          size={24}
          style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
        />
      </View>
    );
```

Open **android/app/build.gradle** and Add below mentioned line after the **react.gradle**.

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Open **android/settings.gradle** Add below Mentioned line.

// Add these two lines

```
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

You Stop the Development server and Rerun the App **react-native run-android**

I Hope, It's helpful.

Comment: For anyone wondering which one to try. This here worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me! Could you please explain us how it works?

Answer (score 11):

I've same issue and than I solved this, let's try :

1. Open `android/app/build.gradle` ( NOT `android/build.gradle` )
2. add the following: `apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")`
3. After that you must stop the Dev, and Restart/Run it again(`npm run android`)

Hopefully this will help you :D

Answer (score 9):

I had everything configured as mentioned in other answers but still running `react-native run-android` i keep seeing the app without the icons!

Simply i did:

`cd android && ./gradlew clean`

then another

`react-native run-android`

And it **worked** yaay!

Comment: I was so stressed about this and couldn't find a solution. But this worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Open android/app/bundle.gradle

[image]

Comment: Please use markdown formatting for code examples, attaching an image is not the best option. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @ijavid This screenshot actually helped me a lot. It gave me line numbers and other context hints. Stack Overflow mods, you guys aren't as smart as you think you are when it comes to being helpful to the world of devs -- but thanks for your work anyway ;)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

when importing the Icon it show something like that.

To fix this run,

```
npx react-native link && npx react-native run android
```

After the command execution

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I am having the same issue and I fixed it this by executing:

npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons
npx react-native run-android

Comment: it should be noted that running react-native link will not always link a package fully, sometimes additional steps are required and you should check carefully with the installation instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the official recommandations (https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android) to have this module loads when creating the bundle :

> Edit android/app/build.gradle ( NOT android/build.gradle ) and add the
>   following:
>
> `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"`

Answer (score 2):

I followed every solution but nothing worked

1. Link command (Link not supported)
2. asset command (config file not exists)

Both didn't worked but at last solution that works is
Adding following lines in build.gradle file

```
"apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Paht of the file is android/app/build.gradle

NOTE:- please use npx react-native run-android command again to see changes

Answer (score 1):

This may have several possible answers:

1- maybe the icon that you use is just for ios ...try to see other logo packs in link below: https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons

2- maybe you import the wrong link for using the package at the top of your code where you import this vector icon, import exact link for example:

this is wrong: `import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons`
and this is true: `"import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";"`

Answer (score 1):

In Android platform icon showed me like this:

[image: problem image here]

after some time of troubleshouting I finally find out solution.

Beacouse of I use my own icon set I created iconSet.ttf from iconSet.svg by IcoMoon App.

In fact I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/bam-tech/add-custom-icons-to-your-react-native-application-f039c244386c

IcoMoon App created *.ttf and selection.json and problem was in selection.json.

I renamed *.ttf file to myIcons.ttf but I had to change fontFamily and name in the end of file selection.json to same name like I named *.ttf file. In my case myIcons.ttf I renamed name and fontFamily to myIcons in selection.json

Answer (score 1):

npm install react-native-vector-icons@9.2.0 --save

This version worked for me !

Comment: Now this is a solution! Thanks for this - it worked instantly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case auto linking was failing. I resolved it by copying Fonts folder from react-native-vector-icons inside node_modules to src/main/assets/fonts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having this problem for android. You would have to do the settings in android folder.

Edit **android/app/build.gradle**  NOT **android/build.gradle** and add the following:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

For more details follow this installation guide.

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android

Answer (score 0):

simplely `npm unlink react-native-vector-icons`,and then `npm link react-native-vector-icons`. (if your ReactNative version is below 0.60)

Answer (score 0):

You can use icons as SVG just by using `selection.json` file. The Developer Experience is very high and requires very little effort.

I hope this module makes your work easier when working with icons.

[react-icomoon](https://github.com/aykutkardas/react-icomoon#react-native---demo)

Answer (score 0):

After adding the font names to my `android/app/build.gradle` it is fixed.

```
project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'Feather.ttf',"FontAwesome.ttf" ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add below android/app/builg.gradle

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

that's all. enjoy your coding...

Answer (score 0):

in my case,
I followed all the documentation steps but the icon was not showing on Android then after that I have check the **fonts.gradle** under

```
projectNameYour/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle
```

then I noticed that there was no file under the `font.gradle`. then uninstall react-native-vector-icons and again install then i checked below files are present there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whatever Icons you are using in your project mention that font name inside project.ext.vectoricons (like FontAwesome.ttf). For my project I have used fontawesome so include fontawesome.ttf.

```
project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf','Ionicons.ttf','FontAwesome.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Add these two lines to **android/app/build.gradle**.

that's all... enjoy your coding...

Answer (score 0):

In Android folder -> App Folder -> Build.gradle file -> dependencies section
Add the follow line like that

`dependencies { implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons') //ADD THIS LINE }`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, using "**vector-icons**" through the default "npm install" can be very annoying sometimes... One alternative way to solve this problem is using the "expo shortcut". The "**vector-icons**" is part of the expo package.

First, you need the **expo** installed:

`$` *npm i -g expo-cli*

You should create your project with 'expo' using:

`$` *npx create-expo-app yourProjectName*

Then, move to your project's paste:

`$` *cd yourProjectName*

Now, run your project with:

`$` *npx expo start*

Code part, now:

Inside one of your file's projects, try to import your desired collection like 'Feather'

`$` *import {Feather} from '@expo/vector-icons'*

Finally, you can use it like this:

`$` *<Feather name={"youIcon'sName"}/>*

I tried many ways with the default "npm install" (https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#installation) with limited success. But on the first try with expo, everything worked like a charm. Sometimes, we only need a different approach...

**Hope it works!**

Best regards for all.

Comment: i want you to format code more so it can be clearly seen

Comment: Thanks. I thought this way would be more organized and clear for everybody. What is your suggestion, @ChiragThummar?

Comment: now it look good

Answer (score 0):

you can use this git page [react-native-vector-icons git page](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) to configure react-native-vector-icons

and if you get an error about the ***classpath*** :

1. go to **node_modules** and find react-native-vector-icon folder
2. Open android folder and open **build.gradle**
   Note: same this ===>>> `project/node_modules/react-native-vector-icon/android`
   and open **build.gradle**
3. and replace ***VER*** with ***+***

   buildscript {
   .....
   dependencies {
   classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:***VER***")
   }
   }

Answer (score 0):

In /android/app/build.gradle change {} by [] in project.ext.vectoricons and add the following line:

import com.android.build.OutputFile

**THIS IS MY ERROR:**
Could not compile build file '/Users/dev/Apps/run/User/android/app/build.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> build file '/Users/dev/Apps/run/User/android/app/build.gradle': 5: Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
> In case you tried to configure a property named 'iconFontNames', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.
> @ line 5, column 20.
> iconFontNames: [ 'Ionicons.ttf' ] // Specify font files

**PATH**: User/android/app/build.gradle:

**File Before solution:**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

project.ext.vectoricons = {
  iconFontNames: [ 'Ionicons.ttf' ] // Specify font files
}
```

apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")

**File After Solution:**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

project.ext.vectoricons = [
  iconFontNames: [ 'Ionicons.ttf' ] // Specify font files
]

apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-    icons/fonts.gradle")

import com.android.build.OutputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case class override issue was also coming as per "[Android Setup](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons?tab=readme-ov-file#android-setup)" guide.

=> *Do not follow all the points on "[Android Setup](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons?tab=readme-ov-file#android-setup)" in my suggestion to avoid above problem*

Only Edit android/app/build.gradle (NOT android/build.gradle) to provide icon path:-

```
apply from: file("../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle")
```