# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons: classpath'

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I was runing a project(contacts from) "fullstack react native" book in react native. but I have a problem with react-native-vector-icons.
when I run `react-native run-android` it showed me bellow error:

```
D:\android_Project\Vitel\React_Nativ\test\ZContacts>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using
 "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 874 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:
classpath'.
   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).

     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-p
roto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development envi
ronment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.htm
l#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8
081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:
classpath'.
   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).

     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-p
roto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (D:\android_Project\Vitel\React_Nativ\test\ZContacts\node
_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\
runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (D:\android_Project\Vitel\React_Nativ\test\ZContacts\node_mod
ules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\inde
x.js:158:41)
    at then.result (D:\android_Project\Vitel\React_Nativ\test\ZContacts\node_mod
ules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\inde
x.js:125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

my Build.gradle is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0')

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

and app/build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile    
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zcantacts"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

again i tried to run a new simple project so i do bellow commands:
I tried a new simple project with this commads:

```
>react-native init testicons

>cd testicons
```

change build.gradle (change classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2") to classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0")
)
then app run with react-native run-android (without import from react-native-vector-icons)
and run these commands:

```
>npm install react-native-vector-icons
```

and

```
>react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

i changed app.js:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React from 'react';
import {View,} from 'react-native';
import { MaterialIcons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
const getTabBarIcon = icon => ({ tintColor }) => (
  <MaterialIcons name={icon} size={26} style={{ color: tintColor }} />
);

const App: () => React$Node = () => {return (<><View >{getTabBarIcon('list')}</View></>);};
export default App;
```

but when I run bellow cammand i had same error as before!

```
react-native run-android
```

that error was:

```
D:\android_Project\Vitel\React_Nativ\testicons>react-native run-android
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the followi
ng modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-
vector-icons")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or
above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <d
ependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn'
t compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library mai
ntainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/
master/docs/autolinking.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using
 "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 867 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:
classpath'.
   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).

     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-p
roto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development envi
ronment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.htm
l#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8
081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:
classpath'.
   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).

     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-p
roto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (D:\android_Project\Vitel\React_Nativ\testicons\node_modu
les\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOn
AllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (D:\android_Project\Vitel\React_Nativ\testicons\node_modules\
@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:
158:41)
    at then.result (D:\android_Project\Vitel\React_Nativ\testicons\node_modules\
@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:
125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

can you help me? what is problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Go to [another question link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77068152/12457780)
This may work for you
**work for me**

Answer (score -1):

Follow this
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android

OR simply u can do 
`react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

Comment: yes. I run it before. but i had error again. when I reviewed CMD, it showed me an error :

Comment: it just the warning you can ignore it.

Comment: Edit android/app/build.gradle ( NOT android/build.gradle ) and add the following:

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

Comment: I did, but the problem remains

Comment: it showwd this error: before that error : `error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the followi
ng modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-
vector-icons")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or
above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <d
ependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn'
t compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library mai
....`

Comment: No I did not clean gradle, how can I do it?

Comment: after running `gradlew clean` it had error: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:
classpath'.
   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).

     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-p
roto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203465/discussion-between-rishikesh-07-and-mohsen-zarrindel).